# Snowflake: Concurrent queries with CREATE OR REPLACE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When running a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE AS` statement in one session, are other sessions able to query the existing table, before the transaction opened by CORTAS is committed?

From reading the usage notes section of the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#usage-notes), it appears this is the case. Ideally I'm looking for someone who's validated this in practice and at scale, with a large number of read operations on the target table.

> Using OR REPLACE is the equivalent of using DROP TABLE on the existing table and then creating a new table with the same name; however, the dropped table is not permanently removed from the system. Instead, it is retained in Time Travel. This is important to note because dropped tables in Time Travel can be recovered, but they also contribute to data storage for your account. For more information, see Storage Costs for Time Travel and Fail-safe.
>
> In addition, note that the drop and create actions occur in a single atomic operation. This means that any queries concurrent with the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE operation use either the old or new table version.
>
> Recreating or swapping a table drops its change data. Any stream on the table becomes stale. In addition, any stream on a view that has this table as an underlying table, becomes stale. A stale stream is

Answer (score 0):

I have not "proving it via performance tests to prove it happens" but we did run for 5 years, where we read from tables of on set of warehouses and rebuilts underlying tables of overs and never noticed "corruption of results".

I always thought of snowflake like double buffer in computer graphics, you have the active buffer, that the video signal is reading from (the existing tables state) and you are writing to the back buffer while a MERGE/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE is running, and when that write transaction is complete the active "current page/files/buffer" is flipped, all going forward reads are now from the "new" state.

Given the files are immutable, the double buffer analogy holds really well (aka this is how time travel works also). Thus there is just a "global state of what is current" maintained in the meta data.

To the CORTAS / [Transaction](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html), I would assume as that is an DDL operation, if you had any transactions that it completes them, like all DDL operations do. So perhaps prior in my double buffer story, that is a hiccup to understand.